# Java webstart stopped working after Java 7 update 45 for jcl-over-slfj4.jar

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

My application is using Java web start with JNLP. After installing all Java 7 related updates my application was running fine but when I added jcl-over-slf4j-1.1.1.jar file in the lib folder then my application stopped working. When I remove it the application worked fine again. 
NOTE: This application is also using Log4j jar file.
Not sure if the issue is with this jar file or with my application.

Here is the corresponding stack trace for this issue:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>       at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.(PropertiesConfiguration.java:222)

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue. The issue is jcl-over-sfl4j.jar file is not mentioned in .jnlp file. Once I mentioned in the file it is working as expected.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).